# Setting display names in a Kendo TreeView, with a simple hierarchical datasource

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm having trouble in displaying, or mapping, the Kendo TreeView's displaynames for my parent and child objects.

The following is used as a base setup of the datasource:

```html
<div id="list-of-devices"</div>
```

```js
// somewhere in my script
var inline = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: [
        {
            "DeviceGroupId": 1,
            "DeviceGroupName": "Superdeluxe Devices",
            "Devices": [
                {
                    "DeviceId": 1000,
                    "DeviceName": "My First Device"
                },
                {
                    "DeviceId": 1001,
                    "DeviceName": "My Second Device"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    schema: {
        model: {
            children: "Devices"
        }
    }

});
```

When I initialize the treeview directly using the `.kendoTreeview` function, it works. Like so:

```js
// initialize the treeview
$("#list-of-devices").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: inline,
    dataTextField: ["DeviceGroupName", "DeviceName"]
});
```

The magic in this part is the last line of code where I set the different **dataTextField** for the group and child items. Again, this works!

However, if I convert this into a MVVM sample, I am not sure how to set it correctly.

The MVVM sample:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="list-of-devices" class="devices"
         data-role="treeview"
         data-text-field="dataTextField" <!-- HOW TO DO THIS? -->
         data-bind="source: data">
     </div>
 </div>
```

```js
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    data: inline,
    dataTextField: ["DeviceGroupName", "DeviceName"] // <-- HOW TO DO THIS?
});

kendo.bind($("#container"), viewModel);
```

Although it does work, e.g. throws no errors, all labels are shown as "undefined" in my treeview.

The question is: how can I set, or bind, the dataTextField accordingly to make the treeview spit out the names of the Groups and Children correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you should do is defining it as:

```
<div id="list-of-devices" class="devices"
     data-role="treeview"
     data-text-field="['DeviceGroupName', 'DeviceName']"
     data-bind="source: data">
 </div>
```

Where you set `data-text-field` to the value as if it were a JavaScript array but between quotes. No need for defining it in your `ObservableObject`.

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/38pk73ty/

Comment: Excellent, that was it!